# Matching a number in a file with Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.4

I have about 15,000 files I need to parse which *could* contain one or more strings/numbers from a list I have. I need to separate the files with matching strings.

Given a string: 3423423987, it could appear independently as "3423423987", or as "3423423987_1" or "3423423987_1a", "3423423987-1a", but it could also be "2133423423987". However, I only want to detect the matching sequence where it is not a part of another number, only when it has a suffix of some sort.

So 3423423987_1 is acceptable, but 13423423987 is not.

I'm having trouble with regex, haven't used it much to be honest.

Simply speaking, if I simulate this with a list of possible positives and negatives, I should get 7 hits, for the given list. I would like to extract the text till the end of the word, so that I can record that later.

Here's my code:

```
def check_text_for_string(text_to_parse, string_to_find):
    import re
    matches = []
    pattern = r"%s_?[^0-9,a-z,A-Z]\W"%string_to_find
    return re.findall(pattern, text_to_parse)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    import re
    word_to_match = "3423423987"
    possible_word_list = [
                    "3423423987_1 the cake is a lie", #Match
                    "3423423987sdgg call me Ishmael",  #Not a match
                    "3423423987 please sir, can I have some more?", #Match
                    "3423423987", #Match
                    "3423423987 ", #Match
                    "3423423987\t", #Match
                    "adsgsdzgxdzg adsgsdag\t3423423987\t", #Match
                    "1233423423987", #Not a match
                    "A3423423987", #Not a match
                    "3423423987-1a\t", #Match
                    "3423423987.0", #Not a match
                    "342342398743635645" #Not a match
                    ]

    print("%d words in sample list."%len(possible_word_list))
    print("Only 7 should match.")
    matches = check_text_for_string("\n".join(possible_word_list), word_to_match)
    print("%d matched."%len(matches))
    print(matches)
```

But clearly, this is wrong. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Try `pattern = r"\b%s_?\W"%string_to_find`-  https://ideone.com/YlNOC2

Comment: That worked perfectly. However, I also want to select it till the end of that string. I mean, I'd like to return 3423423987-1a or 3423423987_1, if that's possible.

Comment: You should better specify what characters are acceptable after the number. Digits,dot and letters are not, - and _ are. But what about comma, braces, or other punctuation characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just want to make sure the number is not matched as part of a, say, float number. You then need to use lookarounds, a lookbehind and a lookahead to disallow dots with digits before and after.

```
(?<!\d\.)(?:\b|_)3423423987(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO0eK6/3)

**To also match the "prefixes"** (or, better call them "suffixes" here), you need to add something like `\S*` (zero or more non-whitespaces) or `(?:[_-]\w+)?` (an optional sequence of a `-` or `_` followed with 1+ word chars) at the end of the pattern.

*Details*:

- `(?<!\d\.)` - fail the match if we have a digit and a dot before the current position
- `(?:\b|_)` - either a word boundary or a `_` (we need it as `_` is a word char)
- `3423423987` - the search string
- `(?:\b|_)` - ibid
- `(?!\.\d)` - fail the match if a dot + digit is right after the current position.

So, use

```
pattern = r"(?<!\d\.)(?:\b|_)%s(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)"%string_to_find
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YlNOC2)

If there can be floats like `Text with .3423423987 float value`, you will need to also add another lookbehind `(?<!\.)` after the first one: `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\.)(?:\b|_)3423423987(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)`

Comment: Sorry for hectic editing, now it looks more or less final.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. Could you show me how to expand the matches till the end of the string? Such as with 3423423987-1a or 3423423987_1?

Comment: Add a `\S*` at the end of the pattern, perhaps. See https://regex101.com/r/sO0eK6/4. Also, if there can be floats like `Text with .3423423987 float value`, you will need to also add another lookbehind: `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\.)(?:\b|_)3423423987(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)`.

Comment: Thank you! I made a small modification, there should be no prefix to the string, so this works for me: `(?<!\d\.)(?:\b)3423423987(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)\S*`

Comment: You taught me more about regex than any damned book :| Thanks!

Comment: I thought your word boundary should exclude `_` symbol. Ok, then you can use a bit simpler syntax: `(?<!\d\.)\b3423423987(?:\b|_)(?!\.\d)\S*` (remove the non-capturing `(?:...)` group around `\b` since this is a grouping construct, but you have just 1 atom there, nothing to group and it affects performance - again, a tiny bit).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:\b|^)3423423987(?!\.)(?=\b|_|$)
```

`(?:\b|^)` asserts that there are no other numbers to the left

`(?!\.)` asserts the number isn't followed by a dot

`(?=\b|_|$)` asserts the number is followed by a non word character, an underscore or nothing

Comment: In case of digit context, `\b|^` is equal to `^` and `\b|$` is equal to `$`.

Comment: Nvm, that worked! Thanks. Now, how do I get the rest of the strings that it matched?

Comment: This solution will find a match in `23.3423423987_1`. Not sure you really want that.

Comment: Oh! No, I do not want that!

Comment: Beware, `\b` stands for *boundary*, where I think that you want blank or space which is `\s`